# Filter for multiple envelope custom_fields

Tags: docusignapi

We have added 2 required custom_fields to our Envelopes that we create through DocuSign.

Now we are trying to fetch these Envelopes and filter them by the value of said Custom fields.
This is working well if we are filtering for 1 value, like in this example:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/ACCOUNT_ID_NUMBER/envelopes?status=sent&custom_field=FIELD1%3DVALUE1
```

Like I mentioned, this works, but we are struggeling to find a way to filter for 2 custom_fields.

We tried some of the usual approaches by using square brackets or using the 'AND' and 'OR' keywords between the filter queries, but none of them seem to be working.

Anyone has an Idea how this could be solved?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the product doesn't support this currently.

Therefore you'll need to make two API calls, one for each custom field. Then your application can compute the intersection of the response envelope ID sets.